# Ao clicar em botão baixar página em PDF

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Olá.. é o seguinte: Eu tenho uma página com campos para serem preenchidos ( http://www.sustentare.net/cartoes/autoconhecimento/ ). Ao clicar em um botão gostaria que ele baixasse essa página com os campos preenchidos como PDF ( uma espécie de "print" da página ).

Eu experimentei  uma solução como vocês podem conferir no link, mas essa solução só é valida para o chrome, onde da para escolher pdf para baixar. Se for usar firefox ou outro navegador já pipoca tudo.

Alguém teria alguma solução para esse meu caso por favor??

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar uma class por exemplo esta http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/ e exportar os dados que queres da base de dados para um pdf.

Aqui tens um exemplo como podes usar o tcpdf para exportar o que pretendes.

```
            <?php

            // Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
            require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

            // create new PDF document
            $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

            // set document information
            $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
            $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
            $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 039');
            $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
            $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

            // set default header data
            $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 039', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

            // set header and footer fonts
            $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
            $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

            // set default monospaced font
            $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

            // set margins
            $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
            $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
            $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

            // set auto page breaks
            $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

            // set image scale factor
            $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

            // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
            if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
                require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
                $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
            }

            // ---------------------------------------------------------

            // add a page
            $pdf->AddPage();

            // set font
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);

            $pdf->Write(0, 'Example of HTML Justification', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

            // Aqui vai os teus dados
            $html = '';

            // set core font
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

            // output the HTML content
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, true);

            $pdf->Ln();

            // set UTF-8 Unicode font
            $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

            // output the HTML content
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, true);

            // reset pointer to the last page
            $pdf->lastPage();

            // ---------------------------------------------------------

            //Close and output PDF document
            $pdf->Output('example_039.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta César, mas eu não tenho uma base de dados. Basicamente o que eu quero é um "print" da página inteira com os campos preenchidos para PDF.

Comment: Ah ok eu vou reformular a resposta com o que você precisa

Comment: @Maicon Base de dados é só um exemplo do César, você pode usar com qualquer coisa o tcpdf :) Basta ler a documentação.

Comment: @CésarSousa Por favor edite a sua resposta e adicione um exemplo de uso do TCPDF, assim provavelmente ganhará alguns votos :)

Comment: Legal @CésarSousa , vou fazer um teste.. valeu!